# Chrome sound control only allows mute or on

Tags: javascript, css, video, types, controls

I have a site containing video content on my website.

However, the sound control only allows mute or on.

The firefox, opera and ie control normally works.

I would ask for help to make it work even in chrome.

Thank you. Get some nice greetings from Slovenia.

Robert.

```
<video id = "myVideo" width = "720" height = "480" controls> 
    <source src = "Goce on the running track.mp4" type = 'video / mp4; codecs = "avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2" '> 
        Your web browser does not support video tags! <a> Upgrade your web browser! </a> 
 </ video> 
<script> 
    var vid = document.getElementById ('myVideo'); 
    vid.volume = 0.05; function playVid () {vid.play (); } 
</ script>
```

Comment: I use the following code:

In html:
  <video id = "myVideo" width = "720" height = "480" controls>
       <source src = "Goce on the running track.mp4" type = 'video / mp4; codecs = "avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2" '>
         Your web browser does not support video tags!
           <a> Upgrade your web browser! </a>
     </ video>

     <script>
       var vid = document.getElementById ('myVideo');
        vid.volume = 0.05;
        function playVid () {vid.play (); }
     </ script>

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new. How do I do this?

Comment: I entered and entered the code separately.

Comment: <video id = "myVideo" width = "720" height = "480" controls> <source src = "Goce on the running track.mp4" type = 'video / mp4; codecs = "avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2" '>

Comment: I do not think the "controls" chrome function supports it

Comment: I mistakenly rolled back the question as I did not see the HTML code that had been eaten up, sorry. If you're posting HTML, please ensure you put 4 spaces in front of the code so it's formatted into a block. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Any idea? I've been looking for two days, and nothing is smart on the web.

Comment: The script is only for this to start with a lower volume.

Comment: Finally, I found a solution: http://www.inwebson.com/demo/html5-video/demo2/and arrange it for my needs. Now a new problem with the Opera. Grrr, are these browsers intended only for scripts to be written only for them and executed only in them? I surrender.

Comment: Link to code:

https://gist.github.com/Trzinka/1a423a9f8db70700a9c6bc30c9f0a07f